# Spark java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I run this code, I get empty collection error in some cases.

```
    val result = df
                  .filter(col("channel_pk") === "abc")
                  .groupBy("member_PK")
                  .agg(sum(col("price") * col("quantityOrdered")) as "totalSum")
                  .select("totalSum")
                  .rdd.map(_ (0).asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce(_ + _)
```

The error happens at this line:

```
.rdd.map(_ (0).asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce(_ + _)
```

When collection is empty, I want `result` to be equal to 0. How can I do it?

Comment: before you convert to rdd, did you check if the dataframe has rows or not? I guess its empty

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: yes, my question is how can I check that it's empty and return 0 if it's empty?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Please check my question (the last line). I somehow deleted it from the question. Thanks.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: So, I don't understand how can I get 0 from assert example of Noam.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: `if (assert(df.take(1).isEmpty)) result = 0 else result ...` ?

Comment: `val result = if(df.take(1).isEmpty) 0 else df .filter(col("channel_pk") === "abc") .groupBy("member_PK") .agg(sum(col("price") * col("quantityOrdered")) as "totalSum") .select("totalSum") .rdd.map((0).asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce( + _)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > When collection is empty, I want result to be equal to 0. How can I do it?

Before you do aggregation, just check if the dataframe has some rows or not

```
val result = if(df.take(1).isEmpty) 0 else df
  .filter(col("channel_pk") === "abc")
  .groupBy("member_PK")
  .agg(sum(col("price") * col("quantityOrdered")) as "totalSum")
  .select("totalSum")
  .rdd.map(_(0).asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce(_ + _)
```

or you can use `count` too

```
val result = if(df.count() == 0) 0 else df
  .filter(col("channel_pk") === "abc")
  .groupBy("member_PK")
  .agg(sum(col("price") * col("quantityOrdered")) as "totalSum")
  .select("totalSum")
  .rdd.map(_(0).asInstanceOf[Double]).reduce(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears only at that line because this is the first time you make some action. before that spark doesn't execute anything (laziness). your df is just empty.
You can verify it by adding before:

`assert(!df.take(1).isEmpty)`

Comment: I noticed that I somehow deleted the last line of my message. There was a question `When collection is empty, I want result to be equal to 0. How can I do it?`

Comment: Then replace the assert with if statement that returns 0 when empty